# How to draw a 2-D graph with 3-D data (x, y and z arrays given) with color coded Z axes representation in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plain 3-D co-ordinates - a set of (x,y,z). I want a 2-D plot of X vs Y with coordinates having larger value of z colored darker than smaller values of z. How do I do that?

Comment: Try [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the matplotlib documentation?

Comment: have you tried imshow or pcolor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you want `scatter`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200, cmap='gray_r')
fig.colorbar(scat)
plt.show()
```

[image]